# When can I use "unforgiveness"?

Tags: word-usage

The word seems to exist, but is in half of the dictionaries and has little usage, except from a link with the Bible I can't really explain.

Is it an actual word ? Can I use it in a paper ?

Comment: Give an example of how you want to use it, please.

Comment: I can't think of sentence I'm proud of, so here goes nothing : "There is a sense of unforgiveness in this race, if he gets any less than first place he can't compete in the Olympics."

Comment: Forget it, no matter _how_ you mean to use it. If you must, you can use _unforgivingness,_ formed from _unforgiving._ But neither is felicitous. Use _coldheartedness,_ or _mercilessness,_ maybe.

Comment: Just write _"The race is unforgiving. Unless he wins, he can't compete in the Olympics."_

Comment: I agree, *unforgiving* is the word you want.

Comment: Then how do you use *unforgiving* to qualify a word ? Like there are two synonyms, but one is "not that bad" while the other "has and idea of unfogivingness". How would you say that using "*unforgiving*" ?